# Issue in back press in fragment when edittext focused

Tags: android-fragments

I am working on fragments and getting one problem when where I tried to get back to my previous fragment on back button press My application get closed (condition when edit text is focused) and the same thing works fine when (Edit text is not focused).

Here is the code which i am using :-

```html
 public static void OnBackPressHandler(View rootView,
   final Fragment fragment, final String fragmentName,
   final String fragmentTitle) {
  rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
  rootView.requestFocus();

  rootView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      Session.ChangeFragment(fragment, fragmentName,
        fragmentTitle);
      return true;
     }
    }
    return false;
   }
  });
 }
```

Here is the code for changing fragment :-

```html
public void onFragmentChange(Fragment fragment, String fragmentName,
   String headerTitle) {
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
    .beginTransaction();
  setHeaderTitle(headerTitle);
  if (sCheckFragment != null) {
   fragmentManager.popBackStack();
   sCheckFragment = fragmentName;
  } else {
   sCheckFragment = fragmentName;
  }
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_main, fragment);
  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentName);
  fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
 }
```

I also tried it by removing focus from edit text by using EditText.clearfocus(); but it doesn't help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally I am able to use it through interface , I just make an interface which will handle my call when user click on Back-Button of his android phone

Here is the piece of code :
Interface which i created :-

```html
public interface OnBackPressHandler {

 void ChangeFragmentOnBackPress(Fragment fragment, String fragmentName,
   String headerTitle);

}
```

Then make its Getter-Setter :-

```html
private static OnBackPressHandler sBackPressHandler;

public static void ChangeFragmentOnBackPressHandler(Fragment fragment,
   String fragmentName, String headerTitle) {
  if (sBackPressHandler != null) {
   sBackPressHandler.ChangeFragmentOnBackPress(fragment, fragmentName,
     headerTitle);
  }
 }

 public static void setBackPressHandler(
   OnBackPressHandler listnerOnBackPressHandler) {
  sBackPressHandler = listnerOnBackPressHandler;
 }
```

Then I implement it in my  MainActivity class
here is its OverRide Method :-

```html
public void ChangeFragmentOnBackPress(Fragment fragment,
   String fragmentName, String headerTitle) {
  mBackPressFragment = fragment;
  mBackPressFragmentName = fragmentName;
  mBackPressFragmentHeaderTitle = headerTitle;
  mIsBackpressFirstTime = false;
 }
```

Then finally i call it in ONBackPress of main activity calss :-

```html
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  if (mIsBackpressFirstTime) {
   finish();
  } else {
   if (mBackPressFragment != null) {
    Session.ChangeFragment(mBackPressFragment,
      mBackPressFragmentName, mBackPressFragmentHeaderTitle);
    mBackPressFragment = null;
    mBackPressFragmentName = "";
    mBackPressFragmentHeaderTitle = "";
   } else {
    finish();
   }
  }
 }
```

Now you need to call simply this given method from any of your fragment :-

```html
Session.ChangeFragmentOnBackPressHandler(
    new HomeFragment(),
    getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.fragment_home),
    getActivity().getResources().getString(
      R.string.title_fragment_home));
```